# Factors of integers of the form $p-2^\lambda n$.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, cryptography, prime-factorization

Here $p$ is an odd prime, $n$ is uniform on $[0, 2^\lambda]$, and $\lambda$ is a constant. We define distribution $\mathcal{D}$ by:
$$x \xleftarrow{\$} p-2^\lambda n$$

Assume $p \approx 2^{4\lambda}$, $\lambda \in \{128, 256\}$, and $0 \leq k \leq \log_2 \lambda$. Do a non-negligible fraction of samples from $\mathcal{D}$ contain a (possibly composite) factor within $\left[2^{3\lambda+k}, 2^{3\lambda+k+2}\right]$? A sample contains an appropriate factor if any subset product of the prime factors satisfies the range requirement.

I'd like to obtain some lower bound on the density of choices of $n$ which lead to an appropriate subset of factors. I'm not sure how to attack this problem.

Answer (score 1):

So you know $\log2\lambda = \{7,8\}$. And $p−2\lambda n \approx 2^{4\lambda} - 2^{\lambda}n$, so the first thing you need to do is establish your domain. Although its too large to calculate individually, perhaps you can look up a very large prime somewhere, and take a ballpark figure for $n=1/$.

You need to find a way to get a prime factorization for $p-2^\lambda$, put it in a totient function and show that it (maybe) has a product in your range.

Good luck, hopefully somebody else knows more than me

Comment: A prime factorization of $p-2^\lambda n$ is inconvenient but obtainable in the case of $0 \leq n \leq 2\lambda$. However, I'm looking to make a theoretical, rather than numerical, observation about the probability of such a product existing for a random choice of $n$.

Comment: If the φ(n)<E for each value in the domain, then it is more likely to be a multiple of [23λ+k,23λ+k+2] . The threshold depends on the ratio of your domain to the range.

Comment: What is $E$ in this context? The ratio is fixed with $p\approx 2^{4\lambda}$ though it could increase to $2^{6\lambda}$ in the extreme case

Comment: 2^4λ - 2^2λ is still well out from 2^3λ. I'm not saying there won't be primes, but the distribution is probably even, and that leaves an incredibly tremendous number of odds that could be lcm's.

Comment: Can you clarify what "well out" refers to? I don't need much precision, just to obtain some lower bound on the density of numbers which contain an appropriate factor.

Answer (score 0):

So I've been thinking this all day, read an article on wired. https://www.wired.com/2014/12/mathematicians-make-major-discovery-prime-numbers/

If you consider the prime number theorem, $ \pi(n)~  N/logN $ it says that the distribution of primes increases with the $log(N)$.

Because you have a static distribution over your domain that is not exponential, the probability of the range being coprime will have even distribution, would be my hypothesis.

And we have from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function)

> "the probability of two randomly chosen numbers being relatively prime is $6/π^2$."

So if I were to choose a value for $E>φ(n)$, I would try $N/loglog(N)$ or $N/2loglogN$.

You may be able to look at the probable distribution and infer your conclusions from that. Is it even feasible to factor $ 2^λ$ (very large) integers? Thinking about it, if you go to the trouble of factoring each integer then there is no need for a totient.